# Scrollbar with extra space when trying to display 4 even quadrants on page using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to display 4 even quadrants with images in them. Each quadrant will have a sidebar that takes up 20% of the main div's width.

I am trying to figure out why I am getting a scrollbar here with a small white gap at the bottom. When I inspect in developer tools it isn't showing as padding or margin.

```css
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .slide {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        .group {
            display: flex;
            width: 50%;
            /* outline: solid 3px #fff; */
        }

        .side {
            width: 20%;
            background-color: red;
        }

        .main {
            background-color: blue;
        }

        img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Display</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="group">
            <div class="main"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/3840x2160/000/fff"></div>
            <div class="side"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
            <div class="main"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/3840x2160/000/fff"></div>
            <div class="side"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
            <div class="main"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/3840x2160/000/fff"></div>
            <div class="side"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
            <div class="main"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/3840x2160/000/fff"></div>
            <div class="side"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's likely the extra space the browser adds below the baseline for letters like g and y. Remove this by reducing the line height

Comment: @Adam I am not understanding. There is no text anywhere in my html.

Comment: @BlakeRivell are the images just placeholders?

Comment: I'm on my phone atm so can't really see very well. I'll have a look on my laptop in a few mins. Brb

Answer (score 1):

It's about your image sizing and your `.main` class not implementing 80% width. Try this:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.slide {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  /* outline: solid 3px #fff; */
}

.side {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
}

.main {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 80%; // Here, missing width 80%
}

img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto; // Changed to auto
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Display</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="group">
        <div class="main"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/3840x2160/000/fff"></div>
        <div class="side"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <div class="main"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/3840x2160/000/fff"></div>
        <div class="side"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <div class="main"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/3840x2160/000/fff"></div>
        <div class="side"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <div class="main"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/3840x2160/000/fff"></div>
        <div class="side"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Basically your image size doesn't fit your layout

Comment: I see a larger gap at the bottom but no scrollbar now. What size do my images have to be?

Comment: I edited because you want width 80% and 20%. Working as intended here, the white you see is your `<body>` element taking your whole screen height.

Comment: I still don't see why we can't make the divs fully full the body. Then the images fully fill the dives regardless of there size. As you can see I am trying a perfect 4K resolution for this quad setup. Since I am adding a side bar maybe I should be doing 3840 x 0.8 = 3072 and use 3072 as my image width? Still unsure why image size matters wouldn't it just stretch to fill its dev even if its not proportionate?

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by the other answer, it's your image size.

It's commonly known that images without `max-width: 100%;` will be very unresponsive. Especially large images like this. Now, when you add `height: 100%;` it's trying to maintain its height within the parent which is causing the white space you see.

You'll notice if you add `flex: 1;` to `.main` the scrollbar disappears but the white space gets larger. This is demonstrating how the images would behave when responsive.

**Solution:** I asked in the comments if the images are placeholders for other elements. If they are, then all you need is `flex: 1;` on `.main`. But if you are going to have large images there I suggest using `background-image`.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.slide {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;
}

.group {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  /* outline: solid 3px #fff; */
}

.side {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
}

.main {
  background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/3840x2160/000/fff');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Display</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="group">
      <div class="main"></div>
      <div class="side"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <div class="main"></div>
      <div class="side"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <div class="main"></div>
      <div class="side"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <div class="main"></div>
      <div class="side"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I was thinking of using background-image also, but usually in such a display you want to put an image and some text or buttons alongside.

Comment: Any chance we can still do this without using background-image? I am pulling the images from a back-end and prefer to use the actual img tag instead of adding styles and displaying as backgrounds. I am still a bit confused as to why there is a chunk of white space at the bottom showing part of the body. I want the size of the grids to make sure they completely fill the body and then the image to simply fill the div it is in regardless of its size. Full screen, no white space.

Comment: @BlakeRivell Adding the actual images you are using in your question may be helpful.

Comment: @Kameron They are 4K resolution images 3840 x 2160. My goal is to make sure if it is displayed on most TVs it will 100% fill the body with no scrollbar or space and the aspect ration of each image will be flawless. I am throwing the one curveball in by adding a 20% width sidebar next to each image.

Answer (score 0):

To give you my point of view.
I think the right way to do it is with a grid layout. I don't think flex wrap suits well this use case. See if I remove an image, the layout stays the same

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  display: grid;
  max-height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; // Split the screen in two equal parts vertically
}

.group {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 4fr 1fr; // Split the screen in 80% and 20% horizontally 
}

.side {
  background-color: red;
}

.main {
  max-height: 50vh;
  min-height: 50vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Display</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="group">
        <div class="main"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/3840x2160/000/fff"></div>
        <div class="side"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <div class="main"></div>
        <div class="side"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <div class="main"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/3840x2160/000/fff"></div>
        <div class="side"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <div class="main"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/3840x2160/000/fff"></div>
        <div class="side"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is a cool way of doing it and we end up with the same result. I am still a bit confused as to why there is a chunk of white space at the bottom showing part of the body. I want the size of the grids to make sure they completely fill the body and then the image to simply fill the div it is in regardless of its size. Full screen, no white space.

Comment: @BlakeRivell I tried to do the math but it is a bit late here haha, all I can say it is about the image Width/Height ratio, not fitting a 80/20 + 80/20 layout. The background image solution will make the image "cover" the `main` div and center itself in said div. The result will grow and crop the image to fit the layout

Comment: @BlakeRivell I edited the code if you want images to fit all TVs like you said, always have 4 grids, and allow to stretch images.